# Is there any way to merge two numpy arrays with a given cost function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, neural-network

For my neural network, I am trying to create a cost function. I am using the following cost function:

```
C = sum((an - yn)^2)
# C = Cost Function, sum = sigma, an = actual_output, yn = desired_output
```

Here is a way in which I implemented it in python:

```
def cost(actual_outputs, desired_outputs):
    # actual_outputs and desired outputs are numpy arrays
    costs = [(actual_output - desired_output) ** 2 for actual_output, desired_output in zip(actual_outputs, desired_outputs)]
    return sum(costs)
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this using numpy (or any other method)?

Comment: What do `actual_output` and `desired_output` look like?

Comment: `costs = sum((actual_output - desired_output) ** 2)` is already the answer provided your both input variables `actual_output` and `desired_output` are NumPy arrays

Answer (score 0):

You could use [linalg.norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html):

```
import numpy as np

def cost(actual_outputs, desired_outputs):
    return np.linalg.norm(np.array(actual_outputs) -  np.array(desired_outputs)) ** 2
```

This answer assumes your input are not numpy arrays, otherwise you can compute using `actual_outputs` and `desired_outputs` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import timeit
import random
import numpy as np
def cost(actual_outputs, desired_outputs):
    # actual_outputs and desired outputs are numpy arrays
    costs = [(actual_output - desired_output) ** 2 for actual_output, desired_output in zip(actual_outputs, desired_outputs)]
    return sum(costs)

def cost2(actual_outputs,desired_outputs):
    return ((actual_outputs-desired_outputs)**2).sum()

actual = [random.random() for _ in range(1000)]
desired = [random.random() for _ in range(1000)]
actual2 = np.array(actual)
desired2 = np.array(desired)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(timeit.timeit('cost(actual,desired)','from __main__ import cost,actual,desired',number=10))
    # 0.00271458847557
    print(timeit.timeit('cost2(actual2,desired2)','from __main__ import cost2,actual2,desired2',number=10))
    # 0.000187942916669
```

looks faster ... assuming its already a numpy array ... it will probably take longer if you have to convert it to a numpy array

the bigger the list size the greater your gains will be